# Can't apply style to RichTextBox elements based on DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, dependency-properties

I have a control that inherits `RichTextBox` (which I'll refer to as `MyRichTextBox`) with a `DependencyProperty` that defines a style for some text element types. Similar to `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`, this style would apply to some of it's children on a per-instance basis.

I have tried doing this two different ways and neither approach works:

1. When creating the text element (a control that inherits `Button` and is hosted in an `InlineUIContainer`; we'll call this `MyTextElement`), I'd create a new style based on `MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle` and assign `MyTextElement` the new style.
2. When `MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle` changes, create a new style based on `MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle` and add to `MyRichTextBox`'s resources.

Both approaches result in the following unexpected exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MS.Internal.PtsHost.UnsafeNativeMethods.PTS.SecondaryException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

No additional information is given and upon researching this exception, I have not found anything as it relates to either `RichTextBox` or programmatically assigning styles. Some articles indicate the error is a threading issue; however, I am not trying to create the style on a different thread and creating/assigning the style *without* basing it on `MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle` *does* work.

This is what the control looks like using approach #2 (I have excluded approach #1 for brevity as it does the same thing, just in a different way):

```
public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static DependencyProperty ItemContainerStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemContainerStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MyRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Style), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnItemContainerStyleChanged));
    public Style ItemContainerStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (Style)GetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty, value);
        }
    }
    static void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Object as MyRichTextBox).OnItemContainerStyleChanged((Style)e.OldValue, (Style)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(Style OldValue, Style NewValue)
    {
        //Make sure the old style is gone
        if (OldValue != null)
            Resources.Remove(OldValue.TargetType);

        if (NewValue != null)
        {
            //This line does not attempt to utilize the specified style, but is stable
            Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType));

            //This line attempts to utilize the specified style, but is unstable
            Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType, NewValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to do this:

```
<Controls:MyRichTextBox>
    <Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MyTextElement}">
            <!-- Whatever... -->
        </Style>
    </Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</Controls:MyRichTextBox>
```

Which should allow me to define a style for all elements of type `MyTextElement` in `MyRichTextBox`. Approach #1 would give an identical result, but both approaches fail with the same error.

Because assigning a new style *without* basing it on `MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle` works, it is unclear what I am doing wrong that is causing this error.

**Edit**:
`MyTextElement` looks like this:

```
public class MyTextElement : Button
{
    public MyTextElement() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

A valid, logical structure of `MyRichTextBox` would look something like this:

```
<Controls:MyRichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Controls:MyTextElement Content="My Content"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
         </Paragraph >
     </FlowDocument>
 </Controls:MyRichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add *one* resource with a key of `NewValue.TargetType` to the `ResourceDictionary`.

The following sample code works fine for me:

```
public class MyTextElement : Run { }

public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static DependencyProperty ItemContainerStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemContainerStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MyRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Style), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnItemContainerStyleChanged));
    public Style ItemContainerStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (Style)GetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty, value);
        }
    }
    static void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Object as MyRichTextBox).OnItemContainerStyleChanged((Style)e.OldValue, (Style)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(Style OldValue, Style NewValue)
    {
        //Make sure the old style is gone
        if (OldValue != null)
            Resources.Remove(OldValue.TargetType);

        if (NewValue != null)
        {
            //This line does not attempt to utilize the specified style, but is stable
            //Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType));

            //This line attempts to utilize the specified style, but is unstable
            Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType, NewValue));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Controls:MyRichTextBox>
    <Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MyTextElement}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="default" />
            <Controls:MyTextElement Text="red" />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</Controls:MyRichTextBox>
```

[image]

**Edit:**

> `MyTextElement` inherits `Button` and is assigned as the child of `InlineUIContainer`; ultimately, the style needs to apply to `MyTextElement`, NOT a `Run`. Your `MyTextElement` inherits `Run` and isn't a child of anything

This works as well:

```
public class MyTextElement : Button
{
    public MyTextElement() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public static DependencyProperty ItemContainerStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemContainerStyle", 
        typeof(Style), typeof(MyRichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Style), 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnItemContainerStyleChanged));
    public Style ItemContainerStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return (Style)GetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty, value);
        }
    }
    static void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Object as MyRichTextBox).OnItemContainerStyleChanged((Style)e.OldValue, (Style)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemContainerStyleChanged(Style OldValue, Style NewValue)
    {
        //Make sure the old style is gone
        if (OldValue != null)
            Resources.Remove(OldValue.TargetType);

        if (NewValue != null)
        {
            Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType, NewValue));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Controls:MyRichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MyTextElement}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Controls:MyRichTextBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Controls:MyTextElement Content="My Content"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph >
    </FlowDocument>
</Controls:MyRichTextBox>
```

Note I have removed the following line from the `OnItemContainerStyleChanged` method:

```
Resources.Add(NewValue.TargetType, new Style(NewValue.TargetType));
```

[image]

Comment: Right, but the line `Resources.Remove(OldValue.TargetType)` ensures whatever style has been added previously with that key (which always has the same target type) gets removed prior to adding the new style. If I were not removing the old resource first, I should get a `Item has already been added` error, but that is not the case. In addition, `MyTextElement` inherits `Button` and is assigned as the child of `InlineUIContainer`; ultimately, the style needs to apply to `MyTextElement`, NOT a `Run`. Your `MyTextElement` inherits `Run` and isn't a child of anything.

Comment: Updated OP to clarify.

Comment: It still works. See my edit. And it is not the Resources.Remove ... line that should be removed, it is the first call to Resources.Add.

Comment: Just found out my issue has to do with a rogue image that couldn't be found. Marking this as the answer anyway because it indeed works!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm doing. I defined a `ContentTemplate` that referenced a nonexistent image and only realized this once I removed it and used your sample. Thanks again!